# Angular2 how to change styles of css classes in typescript?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to toggle viewing categories of items within a very long list, based on what the user wants to see. I want to toggle viewing everything, just meetings, just events or nothing. (this is a small example I really have about 15 categories)

```
<ul>
<li class="cal-meeting">meeting title</li>
<li class="cal-event">event title</li>
<!-- … the list goes on with various events and meetings -->
```

So I have the following checkboxes to toggle the viewable items:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked (click)="toggleCal('meeting')">
<input type="checkbox" checked (click)="toggleCal('event')">
// checkboxes are initially checked however I will make this dynamic saved in DB for user preference
```

In my angular component in TypeScript I have the function:

```
toggleCal(toggle_items) {
   if (toggle_items === 'meeting') {
       // this.display_meeting is initially set to true in ngOnInit
       this.display_meeting = !this.display_meeting;
       if ( this.display_meeting ) {
          // set class cal-meeting to display: block;
       } else {
          // set class cal-meeting to display: none;
       }
   }
// do the same thing if toggle_items === 'event'
}
```

How do I change the display value of the classes cal-meeting and cal-event in my Typescript? I assume just changing the CSS values of the classes is the best way.

I did try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cal-meeting').style.display = 'none';
```

But I get an error saying "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf'"

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)?

Comment: getElementsByClassName gives an array of elements not an element so i think you should use a loop over the elements

Comment: Will it not be better to add an `*ngIf` to the `li` element - `<li class="cal-meeting" *ngIf="display_meeting">meeting title</li>`. This ensures that the item is displayed only when `display_meeting` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 6):

try to convert your selection as HTMLElement

```
const element = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName('cal-meeting')[0];
```

then use :

```
element.style.display = 'none';
```

also you can use *ngif for remove it but if you want to use javascript's function to change style you should convert it to HTMLElement
but you can use angular [ngStyle]="{'property': expression}" for changing style like :

```
<li class="cal-meeting" [ngStyle]="{'display': !this.display_meeting ? 'none': 'block'}">meeting title</li>
```

or you can add class for example if you have class like :

```
.d-none: {display: none}
.d-block: {display: block}
```

you can use it in typescript like:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
hidingClass: string = '';
toggleCal(toggle_items) {
if (toggle_items === 'meeting') {
       this.display_meeting = !this.display_meeting;
       if ( this.display_meeting ) {
          this.hidingClass = 'd-block'
       } else {
          this.hidingClass = 'd-none'
       }
   }
// do the same thing if toggle_items === 'event'
}
```

just use it in your html element:

```
<li class="cal-meeting" [ngClass]="hidingClass">meeting title</li>
```

Comment: Alternatives appreciated. A minor correction according to [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#description), add double quotes (") around the CSS object when using _ngStyles_, i.e `[ngStyle]="{'display': myDisplay; 'color': 'blue'}"`,  to prevent `Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.`.

Comment: Thank You, I forget it

Answer (score 0):

If it's just toggle the view, why you did not put something simple like this

```
<li class="cal-meeting" *ngIf="this.display_meeting">meeting title</li>
```